# Pass paramenter to root component Blazor Assembly

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have a visual Basic project that will render  Blazor Assembly as new feature . I have successfully intergrated together and run them quite smoothly. But I need to pass one string as token such as GUID from parent VB project to blazor directly to root app component.

I am looking a way like :

<app @bind="token" />

or
<app TokenModel="token/>

Thank !

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :) (such as code samples, giving more context of what you are trying to achieve, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App` is the root component, there's no component parent to pass in `token`.  I suggest you use a service to make `token` available to App from wherever you're getting it.  Inject the service into `App` and then read the value in `OnInitialized`.